# calling an function containing an array

Tags: php

Please look at my code:

```
function getShopConfig()
{

$sql = "SELECT sc_name, sc_address, sc_phone, sc_email, sc_shipping_cost, sc_order_email, cy_symbol, sc_currency
        FROM kol_shop_config , kol_currency
        WHERE sc_currency = cy_id";
$result = dbQuery($sql);
$row    = dbFetchAssoc($result);

if ($row) {
    //extract($row);

 $shopConfig = array('name'           => $row['sc_name'],
                        'address'        => $row['sc_address'],
                        'phone'          => $row['sc_phone'],
                        'email'          => $row['sc_email'],
                        'sendOrderEmail' => $row['sc_order_email'],
                        'shippingCost'   => $row['sc_shipping_cost'],
                        'currency'       => $row['sc_currency']);
}
return $shopConfig;  

}
```

then im calling it like,

```
<td colspan="4" align="right"><?php getShopConfig(); echo $shopConfig['name'];?></td>
```

but nothing is being displayed.. where is the mistake?? please help.

note: both are in the same page. dbQuery() and dbFetchAssoc() functions are pre-defined and has worked properly before. if i echo it inside the function and then just call it then its working properly.

Comment: The mistake is that the return value of the `getShopConfig()` function isn't being stored anywhere. The `$shopConfig` variable has nothing to do with the `getShopConfig()` function. For a fix, see hsz's answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php
    $shopConfig = getShopConfig();
    echo $shopConfig['name'];
?>
```

You have to assign returned array to some (`$shopConfig`) variable before.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php $shopConfig = getShopConfig(); ?>

 <td colspan="4" align="right"><?php echo $shopConfig['name'];?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only returning the value but not catching it in any variable.

Try

```
<?php $shopConfig=getShopConfig(); echo $shopConfig['name'];?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is returning a value. You must assign this value to a variable then *then* access the element you want *from that variable*: i.e.

```
<td colspan="4" align="right"><?php $configs = getShopConfig(); echo $configs['name'];?></td>
```

What you are trying to do is use the variable `$shopConfig` which has been declared in the function. This is a local variable and does not exist outside the function. You can make a global `$shopConfig` if you want, but that's a redundant solution since you are returning the array from function. You should avoid global variables as it makes your code more difficult to understand and maintain.

There is, however, a short-hand way of doing this (perhaps you are only using the function to get that element `'name'`) by accessing the return value directly: i.e.

```
<td colspan="4" align="right"><?php echo $getShopConfig()['name'];?></td>
```